# Mocha chai becomes pending with expect() inside it() block with middleware func()

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, chai

I don't know why but this returns the success as pending but the failing successfully returns fail on test using `mocha`

```
describe('createToken', function() {

    it('should return the token', utils.createToken('somestring', function(err, auth){

        expect(typeof auth.token).to.equal('string'); // pending but should be success
        expect(err).to.equal(null); // pending
        expect(true).to.equal(false); // fail

    }));
})
```

What's wrong with me and this code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to test it with `done()` as below

```
describe('createToken', function() {

    it('should return the token', function(done) {
      utils.createToken('somestring', function(err, auth){

        expect(typeof auth.token).to.equal('string'); // pending but should be success
        expect(err).to.equal(null); // pending
        expect(true).to.equal(false); // fail
        done();

      })
   });
})
```

Comment: I recently went through the `mocha docs` and I got mind blown that there's this `done()` function lol. Thanks anyways, I will accept your answer.